# Cleaning of CSV file

Tags: csv

I have a .CSV file with the following entries. The last entry is location.
I wish to extract the latitude and longitude out of it without doing it manually. Can anyone suggest a way of doing it ? Please help.
The 1st 2 entries are :

```
"Type","LicenseNumber","Name","Building","StreetName","Location","City","State","Zip","Tel","Loc"  
"ELECTRONICS STORE",800057,"CAMERA LAND INC",575,"LEXINGTON AVENUE",,"NEW YORK","NY",10022,2127535128,"LEXINGTON AVENUE  
NEW YORK, NY 10022  
(40.7588057463651, -73.9680023077056)"
```

Comment: use regular expressions? what it has to do with PostgreSQL?

Comment: @filiprem what kind of regular expressions are you talking of ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use any programming language with regular expressions. Perl example below.

Save following to a script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
while ( my $line = <> ) {
    #match paretheses, followed by a number, followed by comma, followed by optional space, followed by number, followed by paretheses, followed by end of line
    if ( $line =~ /\((-?\d+\.\d+), ?(-?\d+\.\d+)\)"$/ ) {
        print "Latitude: $1, Longitude: $2\n";
    }
    else {
        print "expression not found in line $.\n";
    }
}
```

and run it on CSV file.

```
$ perl my_script.pl my_file.csv
```

Comment: I have never used perl before !! :-/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the java library you want to use perhaps 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/
and another library http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/
and lastly use split("\,")
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)
to get to your longitude,latitude.

---

hope it helps